# TFS 2012 API - .GetService<WorkItemStore>() Slow

Tags: .net, web-services

I have a custom web service using the TFS API installed on a TFS 2012 server.  After upgrading the TFS server from 2010 to 2012, the following line of code is taking 20 to 30 seconds to execute for my users with every call to the service:

WorkItemStore store = tfsCollection.GetService();

Before the upgrade, the performance for this web service was fine.

Has anyone experienced a performance problem with the TFS 2012 API like this?  Does anyone have a suggestion to resolve this performance issue?

I do have the cache setting WorkItemTrackingCacheRoot configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We worked with MS support to find a solution.  The problem was using the default .NET impersonation in IIS 7.  Each user was getting a temporary cache for all the TFS non-WIT stuff (location service files, etc.) and it was getting regenerated on every call.  We stopped using the default .NET impersonation directly and started using TFS impersonation instead.  This worked because the Application Pool user (service account) is getting the temporary cache created once.   Each user’s identity is passed on to the TFS WIT related calls.

See this blog post for details about TFS impersonation: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/taylaf/archive/2009/12/04/introducing-tfs-impersonation.aspx